# get input from html form in PHP by iterations

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am creating a webpage which display a form with 16 questions, each row of input looks like:

```
<li>*question 1*</li>
<input type="text" name="answer1" style="height: 40px;" size="50" dir="rtl">

<li>*question 2*</li>
    <input type="text" name="answer2" style="height: 40px;" size="50" dir="rtl">
```

and so on - i have 16 (html) lines like that
(by the way, is there a way to prevent this code duplication? this code smells...) and in the end a 'submit' button.

my php script should receive these answers, and put every answer in a variable called "answer(i)" e.g I can write 16 lines of this kind:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $answer1 = $_POST['answer1'];
        $answer2 = $_POST['answer2'];
        ...ect.
        ...
   }
```

this (also) feels like a lot of code duplication. is there a way to make it more general and efficient so that if i'm looking to add some new question I won't have to goo through all this again?
I am new to PHP and HTML, and I though of declaring some functions and call them everytime but when I googled keywords like 'html functions' etc. I didn't find and helping info.
edit: The answers labels maybe different than 'answer1, answer2...' and can be a set of different words ('age', 'gender'...)

Answer (score -1):

You could run a loop to go through the POST array and extract the information into another array.

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
      $$k = $v;
}
```

That will put all of the $_POST data into PHP variables named the same as the form fields generating them (beware you will also get a $submit as well from the button triggering the form).

Comment: actually, it works. can you explain those 2 lines? i'm not sure what the double dollar sign means ('$$k')

Comment: The foreach loop loads the key as well as the value from the POST data (which is an array like any other). The `$$k` bit is a variable variable name. So, it will create a variable named to matche the key from the POST data.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
foreach (range(0,16) as $i)
{
    ${'answer'.$i} = $_POST['answer'.$i];
}
```

or use `extract()`, If you apply on your `$_POST`, keys in your `$_POST` variable gets assigned as variable.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) is official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it's helping but only when the answers are labled as answer1, answer2... etc.
what if my answers have different names such as:
gender, nation, dateOfBirth and so on

Comment: then you can simply use `extract()` like `extract($_POST);`

Comment: care to elaborate? an example would be great

Answer (score -1):

For the HTML use something like this:

```
$questions = array(
    'question1',
    'question2',
    //...
);
foreach($question as $id => $qText){
    ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $qText ?>
        <input type="text" name="answers[]" style="height: 40px;" size="50" dir="rtl">
    </li>
    <?php
}
```

On PHP side you would have your answers in `$_POST['answers']`, it would be an array. And believe me, if you want to put this values from array into separate variables, it is a red flag: something wrong with your code. You do not want to have a set of answers as independent variables.

Comment: that is written pretty weird. the php tags are messed up intentionally?

Comment: there is no mess up if we assume that all the code is inside `<?php ... ?>` block

Comment: you could even have separate variables for answers, if you give keys to `$questions` array:

    `$questions = array('age' => 'How old are you?', ...);`

and change HTML markup a little bit:

    `<?php echo $qText ?>`
    `<input type="text" name="<?=$id ?>" style=... />`